# How to create XSD from Dataset and DatasetTableAdapters classes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ado, strongly-typed-dataset

We have a legacy in-house .Net (ver 4) winforms crud application at my company for which we need to make some changes (e.g. capture additional fields).  Unfortunately the coder who created is long gone and we don't have the source code.  I have very little knowledge of .Net but have I have managed to decompile it using ILSpy (to c#) and fix some compile issues so now it will compile and run.

However, no XSD file is created when decompiling and I now need to make changes to the typed dataset.

Is there anyway to create the XSD file from the Dataset and DatasetTableAdapter classes?

Thanks in advance for your hesitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet object has a WriteXmlSchema method in-built. It can be used like this-

```
DataSetObj.WriteXmlSchema(@"C:\yourApp\yourSchema.xsd");
```

Comment: [Link to the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexmlschema(v=vs.110).aspx)